# Can a NET Standard library reference another NET Standard library?

Tags: c#, .net

I've inherited a bunch of net framework 4.71 solutions, and two net core 2.1 solutions.

I need to write a library for blob storage that can be used by both of them.  I found that the net framework won't call a net core library, and a net core framework won't call the net framework library.  So I was in the midst of trying a couple of net standard 2.1 libraries. (one for external models and one for the blob storage functions)

I haven't even gotten to the point of making sure that the net core and net framework projects can reference net standard libraries.

Question 1) can net framework and net core reference net standard libraries?

Question 2) is there a way to even share code between net core and net framework or should I just work on creating duplicate libraries?

Edit: I did just finally figure out what I was doing wrong in referencing the net standard model project from the blob storage net standard project.  I had to add the project reference directly.  Haven't had to do that in a long time. Visual Studio would add it for me with net framework.

Edit2: looks like I'm just an idiot.  I finally figured out that I needed to also manually add the project reference for the library to the net core project.  Now it compiles.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: 3 x "yes". Can you please provide more details on which errors you encountered when you tried it?

Comment: .NET Framework does not support net standard 2.1, depending on version it supports up to 2.0. Also net standard libraries should be able to reference net standard libraries with the same or less version.

Comment: @KlausGütter more like 3 x "it depends" =)

Comment: @GuruStron right are you; did not notice the "netstandard 2.1"

Comment: Make sure you use Net 4.7.2 or later.  Earlier version have issues targeting Core.

Comment: @KlausGütter your comment really helped. I went back to look at what I did to figure out why it wasn't working for me, and I realized I needed to manually add the project reference here too. doh!  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can net standard libraries reference other net standard libraries?

yes; a netstandard2.0 library can reference another netstandard2.0 library; a netstandard2.1 library can reference netstandard2.0 and netstandard2.1 libraries

> can net framework and net core reference net standard libraries

.NET Framework 4.7.1 can *allegedly* reference netstandard2.0 libraries, although it has some assembly-binding-redirect problems in a few areas ("unsafe", "buffers", etc) - and some areas are simply glitchy; it cannot reference netstandard2.1 libraries

.NET Core can reference netstandard libraries; these days you shouldn't really be looking at .NET Core below .NET Core 3.1, which means it can reference both netstandard2.0 and netstandard2.1 libraries

> is there a way to even share code between net core and net framework or should I just work on creating duplicate libraries

multi-targeting is also an option, if netstandard doesn't work well for you; you can use `<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net471</TargetFrameworks>`, for example, and use `#if` as necessary to switch between target-specific implementations.

Comment: Marc Gravell:  I'm not sure I can really switch the existing 2.1 net core projects to net core 3.1.  I'm not sure how much will break in the process.  There's likely a reason my predecessor didn't do that himself last year.    But that multitargetting idea is interesting. It might be just what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: @justanotherdev OK, but official support end-of-life for .NET Core 2.1 is August 21 this year, so: less than four months (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)

Comment: @MarkGravell I will be eventually upgrading the two net core apps to 3.1 but I just don't have time at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In additional to the excellent answer by Marc I would like to add the [.net standard support matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) that shows what .net version support what .net standard version.

The way I understand it, the intended migration strategy is something like this

1. Migrate the core libraries to .net standard 2.0 (or lower), starting with the libraries with the fewest dependencies.
2. Migrate the applications, UI projects, and any other project that depends on things outside .net standard.
3. Migrate the core libraries to .Net core or .Net 5. [No new versions of .net standard will be released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/). So to use any new features the libraries need to be updated to .net core/5/6 etc.

This way should limit the number of projects that need to be updated at once. Allowing migration to be done piecemeal rather than all at once.